# How to show trailing zeros on plot axis

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a time series.  However, I have not been able to change the precision of the labels on the y axis to always show two numbers after the decimal point. For example, my code plots (0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15...) instead of the desired (0.00, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15...). I have tried this:

```
y <- round(yticks, 2) 
axis(2, at = y, labels = y)
```

Confusingly, this works but it reduces the precision to 1 decimal place.

My complete plotting code:

```
my_time_series = ts(my_data_vec, start=c(1997,9), end=c(2018,4), frequency=12)

xticks <- seq(1997, 2018, 1)
yticks <- seq(0.00, 0.40, 0.05)

plot(my_time_series, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0,0.40))

axis(2, at=yticks, labels=yticks)
axis(1, at=xticks, labels=xticks, tck=-0.01)
```

Comment: Can you provide `TimeseriesM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your labels argument from numeric to character in a way that keeps the trailing zeros.  Here's one option:

```
axis(2, at=yticks, labels=sprintf("%.2f", yticks))
```